# Having difficulties with example 6, pg. 143, in Munkres' Topology.

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I don't know how to prove that $A$ has no limit points. I maybe have to prove it by showing that for any point $(x, n), x \not= 1/n$ in $X$, one of its neighborhood does not intersect $A$, but I'm difficulties with how to rigorously show that.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: All points of $A$ are isolated, and the sequence $\{x_n\}$ does not have a limit.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $U_n=[0,1]\times\{n\}$; then $U_n$ is an open nbhd of $x_n$ in $X$, and $U_n\setminus\{x_n\}$ is open in $X$. (Why?) Now express $X\setminus A$ in terms of the sets $U_n\setminus\{x_n\}$.

Comment: It's past 3 am and this might not be right but if I understand correctly that $X = [0, 1] \times \mathbb{Z^+}$ then $U_n$ is open since it equals $X \cap  U\times V$, where $U=(-1, 2), V=(n-1/2, n + 1/2)$. Further, $U_n - A$ is open because that equals $X \times \mathbb{Z^+} \cap C \times D$, where $C = (-1, 1/n) \cup (1/n, 2), D = V$. This is correct, I hope.

Comment: @Acid2: Yes, it’s correct, though the second part is unnecessarily complicated: $U_n\setminus\{x_n\}$ is open in $X$ because $U_n$ is open in $X$ and $\{x_n\}$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: I told you it's late. But thanks for your help.

Comment: @Acid2: You’re welcome.